# XAML and C# WebView not working in Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, webview

I'm trying to test a `WebView` by showing a local html file. The problem is, webview doesn't show anything.

My `XAML` portion is like bellow:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock x:Name="onlineTestHeadingText"
            Text="Welcome to online test!"
            FontSize="24"
            Foreground="Red"/>
        <WebView x:Name="onlineTestWebView" 
               />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

C# portion is:(edited: relative path corrected)

```
public sealed partial class OnlineTest : Page
{

    Uri url;
    public OnlineTest()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
    /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        url = onlineTestWebView.BuildLocalStreamUri("myUrl", "/problem_page/test.html");
        StreamUriWinRTResolver myResolver = new StreamUriWinRTResolver();

        onlineTestWebView.NavigateToLocalStreamUri(url, myResolver);
    }
}
```

Helper class implementation is:

```
public sealed class StreamUriWinRTResolver : IUriToStreamResolver
{
    public IAsyncOperation<IInputStream> UriToStreamAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        if (uri == null)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        string path = uri.AbsolutePath;

        // Because of the signature of the this method, it can't use await, so we 
        // call into a seperate helper method that can use the C# await pattern.
        return GetContent(path).AsAsyncOperation();
    }

    private async Task<IInputStream> GetContent(string path)
    {
        // We use a package folder as the source, but the same principle should apply
        // when supplying content from other locations
        try
        {
            Uri localUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///html" + path);
            StorageFile f = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(localUri);
            IRandomAccessStream stream = await f.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            return stream.GetInputStreamAt(0);
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw new Exception("Invalid path"); }
    }
}
```

Comment: only problem with above xaml and c# was that I didn't set the property of the html file to "content"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 problems I can find:

1. your webview doesn't have height and width. Please assign the value and test again.
2. You may get the wrong folder. Based on the folloiwng code, the uri will be `ms-appx:///html/html/problem_page/test.html`. Is that the uri you expected?

`url = onlineTestWebView.BuildLocalStreamUri("myUrl", "/html/problem_page/test.html");`

...

`Uri localUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///html" + path);`

Comment: yes, there was problem with relative path of the html contents. thanks anyway!